# How to make reference just to one element from many? vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Im learning vue and Im having this problem. I have about 25 buttons, The only thing that changes is **label** and **ref**. Each one looks like this:

```
<Button
    icon="pi pi-check"
    type="button"
    label="Min"
    class="p-button-text"
    ref="Min"
    @click="showActivatedButton"
    v-bind:class="{ buttonActivated: buttonState }"
/>
```

**In data I have this:**

```
buttonState: false;
```

**In methods I have this:**

```
showActivatedButton() {
    this.buttonState = !this.buttonState;
}
```

**In style I have this:**

```
.buttonActivated {
    background: rgba(62, 70, 76, 0.16);
    color: #3e464c;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

So the idea is once I click one of the buttons, this class .buttonActivated will be added just to THAT button, and if I click it the same button again, the class is removed. As you see it now, it adds and removes the class to every single button, no matter which one I clicked. Please Help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate reactive `buttonState` property for each button. Currently you only have one `buttonState`, which is shared between all the buttons. I would recommend creating a child component which you can reuse for each button, and declare `buttonState` inside the `data()` of the child component.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="(button, index) in buttons"
      :key="index"
    >
      <Button
        icon="pi pi-check"
        type="button"
        :label="button.label"
        class="p-button-text"
        ref="button.ref"
        @click="button.active = !button.active "
        v-bind:class="{ buttonActivated: button.active }"
      />

    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      buttons: [
        { href: 'whatever', label: 'whatever', active: false },
        { href: 'whatever1', label: 'whatever1', active: false }
        ...add buttons
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.buttonActivated {
  background: rgba(62, 70, 76, 0.16);
  color: #3e464c;
  border: 1px solid;
}
</style>
```